# Using a cookie to store and call an integer

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I'm trying to use a cookie to store an integer value for a switch.

```
private int LessonSlideNum;
```

I get:

> **FormatException** Input string was not in a correct format

on this line:

```
LessonSlideNum = Convert.ToInt32(testCookie.Value);
```

or this one:

```
LessonSlideNum = Int.Parse(testCookie.Value);
```

when I use this code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie testCookie = Request.Cookies["TestCookie"];
        if (testCookie == null)
        {
            testCookie = new HttpCookie("TestCookie");
            testCookie.Path = "~/App_Data/Cookies";
            Response.Cookies.Add(testCookie);
        }
        else
        {
            LessonSlideNum = Convert.ToInt32(testCookie.Value);
        }
        Response.Cookies.Add(testCookie);
    }
```

It seems that VS is expecting something in DateTime format. Could someone please help me out here? Thanks :)

Comment: What is the value of Cookie before you convert it to Int32 ? have you checked that on break point ?

Comment: testCookie.Value = "" according to the debugger, before the exception. Its value doesn't change when the exception is raised.

Comment: So the error is correct because there is no integer value in your cookie at the time of conversion. You must make sure that your cookie has a value first before you convert it to integer. at this stage you are only checking the null value but any other non integer value such as ""(empty string) also raise an error when you try to convert it to integer.

Comment: That did it. Thanks @AliShahrokhi! I still wonder why 'if(testCookie == null)' didn't catch the error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that I had no values in the actual cookie. Thanks Ali Shahrokhi! Still, I find it strange that  the line:

```
if(testCookie == null)
```

didn't catch this error...

Comment: Because testCookie wasn't null, its value was just empty. The check would have needed to be `if(testCookie == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(testCookie.Value))`

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaah makes more sense. Something was missing. Thank you @grin0048